# How to create a custom error message in Django log in form?

Tags: django

I am making a login page for my Django app. At the moment, if I enter the wrong username or password the following error message shows up:

[image: error].

Is there a way that I could customise this message to get rid of the "___all____" and the bullet points? Perhaps just saying "Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive."?

A simplified version of my code is below:

views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
```

html:

```
<div class="form_container">
    <form class="log_in_form" action="{% url 'inventory_management_app:login' %}" method="post">
    <p>
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ form.username }}
    </p>

    <br><br>

    <p>
    {{ form.password }}

    <br>

    {{ form.errors }}
    </p>
    <p>

    <br><br>

  <input id="search-button" class="btn btn-dark" type="submit" value="Login">
  </form>
  </p>
  </div>
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.forms.widgets import PasswordInput, TextInput


class CustomAuthForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=TextInput(attrs={'class':'validate','placeholder': 'Email'}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Password'}))
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, name='login', kwargs={"authentication_form":CustomAuthForm}),
```

EDIT: Following marxin's answer allowed me to create a custom message. However, my message was still displaying as a bullet point, a screenshot is below:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After implementing marxins answer, I was still getting difficulties removing the bullet points from my custom message. I found that by just changing my template to include the following code, I could customise my error message without altering anything in my forms.py. The rest of my code is identical to the code given in the question but I have added this:

```
{% if form.errors %}
    <p>my custom error message</p>
{% endif %}
```

So now my HTML looks like this:

```
<form class="log_in_form" action="{% url 'inventory_management_app:login' %}" method="post">
  <p>

  {% csrf_token %}

  {{ form.username }}
  </p>

  <br>

  <p>
  {{ form.password }}
  <br>
  <p>
  </p>
  <br>

  {% if form.errors %}
      <p>username or password not correct</p>
  {% endif %}

  </p>
  <p>
  <br><br>
  <input id="search-button" class="btn btn-dark" type="submit" value="Login">
  </form>
```

Comment: But in this code , you will have the same error message  in the case of  incorrect login  user is  inactive

Answer (score 7):

Change invalid_login error message in your form class.

```
class CustomAuthForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.error_messages['invalid_login'] = 'Custom error'
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: This works great, thank you! The only problem is, my error message is still appearing in bullet points. I have to change the display of {{ form.errors }} in my HTML to show the message without bullet points. Do you know how I could do this Marxin?

Comment: {{ form.errors }} is most likely a dictionary so you should be able to iterate over it in template. {% for key, msg in form.errors.items %} {{ key }} {{ msg }} {% endfor %}

Comment: Ah! This removes the first bullet point but it still displays the sub message "custom error" as a bullet point

Comment: I'm adding in the new screenshot to my question

Comment: I found an alternative answer that is simpler to implement and does not result in bullet points and dictionary for loops so I am not going to accept your answer. I have voted it up as an alternative answer for someone to try if it suits their specific needs..

Answer (score 0):

You can use form validation to introduce a custom method. please refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other

Comment: How would I specifically implement this for a login form?

Comment: using a clean method on your form class.